# CSS - Slant doesn't work when parent background has a colour set

Tags: html, css

There is just a white band appearing if the parent container has a background colour set. Please advise

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ygamrxkd/2/

```css
div {
  background-color:white;
}
.slant {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 5em 1em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}
.slant:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #193654;;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2 class="slant">Header here</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing the z-index on the class seems to work but was wondering if that was the correct approach

Answer (score 1):

This is a `z-index` issue. As you put `z-index:-1` onto the slant it dissappears, because it gets pushed behind the parent element with the background-color. You can solve this by adding `z-index:1` onto the `.slant`, which pushes both elements above the background-color from the parent element.

```css
div {
  background-color:white;
}
.slant {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 5em 1em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:1;
}
.slant:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #193654;;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2 class="slant">Header here</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks as if it's displaying normally to me apart from your text color is the same as the background color.  This just seems to simple though, am I missing something more complicated

```
div {
  background-color:white; //this is white
}
.slant {
  color: #fff; //this is also white
}
```

SCRAP THE ABOVE:

It's the z-index issue as stated in the other answers but you need to set a negative margin on your `<div>` - I would also give it a class name so it doesn't conflict with the rest of your code.

```
div {
  background-color:white;
  z-index:-999;
}
.slant {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 5em 1em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slant:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #193654;;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove negative z-index from `:after` element and your text in `span` tag and add relative  position with z-index init.

```css
div {
  background-color:white;
}
.slant {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 5em 1em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}
.slant span{
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.slant:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #193654;;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  //z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2 class="slant"><span>Header here</span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on `.slant` class a `z-index:0`, your slant background will show.

```
.slant {
    /* here */

    /* your codes */
    z-index: 0;
}
```